# Memory allocation in VMware server running Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, debian, vmware, virtualization, otrs

I have a virtual machine running Debian Stretch with an OTRS instance. During the day sometimes the load average increase a lot (30 or 40) and stay stalled for 10 minutes. Looking in dmesg I could see there is no allocation of High Memory by the kernel. I suspect that VMware is not managing memory very well with this kernel version.

Here follow my dmesg output.

> [328786.492071] /usr/sbin/apach: page allocation stalls for 10160ms,
>   order:0,
>   mode:0x1604050(GFP_NOFS|__GFP_COMP|__GFP_RECLAIMABLE|__GFP_NOTRACK),
>   nodemask=(null) [328786.492095] /usr/sbin/apach cpuset=/
>   mems_allowed=0 [328786.492105] CPU: 0 PID: 31845 Comm: /usr/sbin/apach
>   Not tainted 4.14.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 Debian 4.14.13-1~bpo9+1
>   [328786.492108] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual
>   Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 04/05/2016
>   [328786.492109] Call Trace: [328786.492178]  dump_stack+0x5c/0x85
>   [328786.492202]  warn_alloc+0x114/0x1b0 [328786.492211] 
>   __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x8e0/0xe90 [328786.492214]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x22e/0x250 [328786.492225]  cache_grow_begin+0x80/0x530 [328786.492235]  ?
>   cache_grow_begin+0x80/0x530 [328786.492237] 
>   fallback_alloc+0x161/0x200 [328786.492238] 
>   kmem_cache_alloc+0x1c8/0x5a0 [328786.492321]  ?
>   ext4_find_entry+0x41e/0x4d0 [ext4] [328786.492336] 
>   ext4_alloc_inode+0x17/0x190 [ext4] [328786.492353] 
>   alloc_inode+0x18/0x80 [328786.492364]  iget_locked+0xe0/0x1b0
>   [328786.492379]  ext4_iget+0x3c/0xb50 [ext4] [328786.492401] 
>   ext4_lookup+0xe7/0x270 [ext4] [328786.492410]  lookup_slow+0xa3/0x170
>   [328786.492417]  walk_component+0x1c0/0x350 [328786.492419]  ?
>   path_init+0x1bd/0x300 [328786.492421]  path_lookupat+0x73/0x220
>   [328786.492423]  filename_lookup+0xb8/0x1a0 [328786.492433]  ?
>   strncpy_from_user+0x48/0x160 [328786.492435]  ? vfs_statx+0x73/0xe0
>   [328786.492436]  vfs_statx+0x73/0xe0 [328786.492442] 
>   SYSC_newstat+0x39/0x70 [328786.492448] 
>   system_call_fast_compare_end+0xc/0x6f [328786.492457] RIP:
>   0033:0x7fb3fb333085 [328786.492458] RSP: 002b:00007fb3f202c9c8 EFLAGS:
>   00000246 [328786.492462] Mem-Info: [328786.492470] active_anon:787328
>   inactive_anon:159346 isolated_anon:517
>                    active_file:1901 inactive_file:1760 isolated_file:0
>                    unevictable:0 dirty:19 writeback:16102 unstable:0
>                    slab_reclaimable:3667 slab_unreclaimable:8298
>                    mapped:2772 shmem:1052 pagetables:4641 bounce:0
>                    free:21621 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0 [328786.492475] Node 0 active_anon:3149312kB inactive_anon:637384kB active_file:7604kB
>   inactive_file:7040kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):2068kB
>   isolated(file):0kB mapped:11088kB dirty:76kB writeback:64408kB
>   shmem:4208kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 2027520kB
>   writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? no [328786.492476]
>   Node 0 DMA free:15792kB min:268kB low:332kB high:396kB
>   active_anon:112kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB
>   unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB
>   mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB
>   local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB [328786.492479] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2948
>   3884 3884 3884 [328786.492482] Node 0 DMA32 free:54780kB min:51088kB
>   low:63860kB high:76632kB active_anon:2344948kB inactive_anon:608224kB
>   active_file:7860kB inactive_file:6404kB unevictable:0kB
>   writepending:62236kB present:3129152kB managed:3045596kB mlocked:0kB
>   kernel_stack:1824kB pagetables:8524kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB
>   local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB [328786.492485] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 936
>   936 936 [328786.492488] Node 0 Normal free:15912kB min:16224kB
>   low:20280kB high:24336kB active_anon:804256kB inactive_anon:29732kB
>   active_file:132kB inactive_file:544kB unevictable:0kB
>   writepending:2400kB present:1048576kB managed:958920kB mlocked:0kB
>   kernel_stack:6352kB pagetables:10040kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB
>   local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB [328786.492491] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
>   [328786.492493] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB (M) 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB
>   (U) 2*128kB (UM) 2*256kB (UM) 1*512kB (M) 2*1024kB (UM) 0*2048kB
>   3*4096kB (M) = 15792kB [328786.492502] Node 0 DMA32: 138*4kB (UME)
>   283*8kB (UME) 219*16kB (UME) 183*32kB (UME) 163*64kB (UME) 82*128kB
>   (UE) 38*256kB (ME) 14*512kB (ME) 1*1024kB (M) 2*2048kB (M) 0*4096kB =
>   55120kB [328786.492512] Node 0 Normal: 489*4kB (UME) 283*8kB (UME)
>   117*16kB (UME) 51*32kB (UME) 16*64kB (E) 10*128kB (E) 5*256kB (ME)
>   3*512kB (UE) 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (U) 0*4096kB = 15916kB
>   [328786.492522] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0
>   hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB [328786.492523] 28249 total
>   pagecache pages [328786.492524] 23467 pages in swap cache
>   [328786.492525] Swap cache stats: add 99024, delete 75557, find
>   1611/1880 [328786.492526] Free swap  = 3518180kB [328786.492526] Total
>   swap = 3910652kB [328786.492527] 1048429 pages RAM [328786.492527] 0
>   pages HighMem/MovableOnly [328786.492528] 43324 pages reserved
>   [328786.492528] 0 pages hwpoisoned [328786.543961] /opt/otrs/bin/c:
>   page allocation stalls for 10180ms, order:0,
>   mode:0x14280ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_ZERO), nodemask=(null)
>   [328786.543984] /opt/otrs/bin/c cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
>   [328786.543994] CPU: 1 PID: 31859 Comm: /opt/otrs/bin/c Not tainted
>   4.14.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 Debian 4.14.13-1~bpo9+1 [328786.543995] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop
>   Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 04/05/2016 [328786.543996] Call Trace:
>   [328786.544086]  dump_stack+0x5c/0x85 [328786.544110] 
>   warn_alloc+0x114/0x1b0 [328786.544119] 
>   __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x8e0/0xe90 [328786.544123]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x22e/0x250 [328786.544136]  alloc_pages_vma+0x7c/0x1c0 [328786.544148] 
>   __handle_mm_fault+0xcc6/0x10e0 [328786.544155]  handle_mm_fault+0xc6/0x1b0 [328786.544168] 
>   __do_page_fault+0x266/0x500 [328786.544182]  ? page_fault+0x36/0x60 [328786.544183]  page_fault+0x4c/0x60 [328786.544197] RIP:
>   0033:0x7fb3fb2d04f5 [328786.544198] RSP: 002b:00007fb3e6ff1eb0 EFLAGS:
>   00010202 [329015.921431] /opt/otrs/bin/c: page allocation stalls for
>   11684ms, order:0, mode:0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE),
>   nodemask=(null) [329015.921437] /opt/otrs/bin/c cpuset=/
>   mems_allowed=0 [329015.921452] CPU: 1 PID: 31862 Comm: /opt/otrs/bin/c
>   Not tainted 4.14.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 Debian 4.14.13-1~bpo9+1
>   [329015.921453] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual
>   Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 04/05/2016
>   [329015.921454] Call Trace: [329015.921465]  dump_stack+0x5c/0x85
>   [329015.921470]  warn_alloc+0x114/0x1b0 [329015.921473] 
>   __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x8e0/0xe90 [329015.921476]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x22e/0x250 [329015.921481]  alloc_pages_vma+0x7c/0x1c0 [329015.921484] 
>   __read_swap_cache_async+0x145/0x1d0 [329015.921493]  read_swap_cache_async+0x28/0x60 [329015.921495] 
>   swapin_readahead+0x220/0x270 [329015.921498]  ?
>   __lock_page_or_retry+0x202/0x330 [329015.921502]  ? radix_tree_lookup_slot+0x1e/0x50 [329015.921504]  ?
>   find_get_entry+0x19/0xc0 [329015.921506]  ?
>   pagecache_get_page+0x30/0x220 [329015.921509]  ?
>   do_swap_page+0x325/0x7a0 [329015.921510]  do_swap_page+0x325/0x7a0
>   [329015.921515]  __handle_mm_fault+0x7ae/0x10e0 [329015.921518] 
>   handle_mm_fault+0xc6/0x1b0 [329015.921522] 
>   __do_page_fault+0x266/0x500 [329015.921525]  ? page_fault+0x36/0x60 [329015.921526]  page_fault+0x4c/0x60 [329015.921529] RIP:
>   0033:0x7fb3fb2d0d60 [329015.921530] RSP: 002b:00007fb3e57f1810 EFLAGS:
>   00010206 [329015.921532] warn_alloc_show_mem: 1 callbacks suppressed
>   [329015.921533] Mem-Info: [329015.921540] active_anon:785610
>   inactive_anon:158508 isolated_anon:544
>                    active_file:2917 inactive_file:2497 isolated_file:0
>                    unevictable:0 dirty:9 writeback:15378 unstable:0
>                    slab_reclaimable:3744 slab_unreclaimable:8254
>                    mapped:4479 shmem:768 pagetables:5044 bounce:0
>                    free:21678 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0 [329015.921546] Node 0 active_anon:3142440kB inactive_anon:634032kB active_file:11668kB
>   inactive_file:9988kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):2176kB
>   isolated(file):0kB mapped:17916kB dirty:36kB writeback:61512kB
>   shmem:3072kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 1740800kB
>   writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? no

I'm running out of ideas or ways to troubleshoot  this issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

What is the VMware platform? ESXi? Workstation?